# Can't access OVM Samba share MacOs / iOS (Invalid argument)

Tags: ios, macos, raspberry-pi, samba, openmediavault

I have Open Media Vault set up on Raspberry Pi. I have connected an external drive, created the required shared folders, enabled SMB/CIFS.

Everything works great on Windows machine and Android devices, however, if I try to connect to the share through MacOS or iOS (files app), I get an error:

**MacOS**: There was a problem connecting to the server “raspberrypi”.

**iOS**: The operation couldn't be completed. Invalid argument

OMV is a default latest installation, no custom configs or anything.
The external drive is exFat type, it was working fine on pure Samba server before (without OMV).

Any ideas how can I fix this or at least how can I debug why I can't connect from MacOS and iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if problem still persists on your side but enabling FTP server solved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

Fix:

```
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/smbfs.kext
```

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/659331?login=true